# Binary Packer Collection

Tags: portable-executable, packer

does anybody knows where I can get a collection of PE Packers or Protectors (like: upx, ASProtect, Themida, etc)?

well I already find a collection from "tuts4you.com" for Unpackers: http://mirror7.meh.or.id/Reverse%20Engineering/Best_Reverse_Collection/Unpacking%20Tutorials/

I wonder if anybody knows where can I find a collection for packers (not Unpackers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I finally found some collection for binary compressors and protectors.

here in [Aaron' Homepage](http://www.exetools.com/protectors.htm) you can find a collection for Compressors, Protectors, File-Analyzers, Unpackers, Debuggers, Disassemblers, Hex-Editors, Patchers and son on.